# NoClassDefError (CTTableColumnsImpl$1TableColumnList) in poi-ooxml-schemas Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, runtime, noclassdeffounderror

When running my application I get the NoClassDefFoundError (catched by catching a Throwable). The class it cannot find is:
`org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTTableColumnsImpl$1TableColumnList`

Under `pom.xml` I have `poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12.jar` and when browsing the jar file (in the package explorer in Eclipse) I can see the `CTTableColumnsImpl.class` file
(Not the inner class `TableColumnList` though).

I get the error only at runtime.

Anybody got a clue?

Thanks.